# Get variable name from input string without using an elif statement for all possibilities

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

I'm new to programming in Python 3.4.3 but I've started my first project that will help me as a chemist. I've created a series of code that asks the user to input the name of a chemical (e.g. water or ethanol) and then returns a list of chemical properties of the chemical. My code is below. I left out the chemical data I hard coded to make it easier to read hopefully.

```py
print ("Welcome to [program name]! Copyright (C) 2015 [name omitted] All Rights Reserved.")

print ("----" * 4)

class Chemical():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def getData(self):
        return self.data 

chemical1 = Chemical("Data\nData\nData\n")
chemicalName = input("Choose a chemical: ")
if chemicalName == "chemical1":
    print (chemical1.getData())
elif chemicalName == "Other chemical name":
    # I now have a lot of elif statements, to account for all possible chemicals
    print (other_chemical.getData())
else:
    print ("\nThe chemical you chose hasn't been added yet\n")
```

When executed, if the input is chemical1 what will be produced is:

```py
data
data
data
```

Basically, I have a huge list of chemicals with their data hard coded into the script and a large number of elif statements to account for each chemical (there are now 26 chemicals). The whole thing works perfectly but I would like to reduce the number of elif statements in order to reduce the number of lines of code. Perhaps by writing a for loop or some other expression as suggested by a friend of mine who has some experience with Python. I'm still a beginner so I'm not sure of all the different methods.

I tried this:

```py
chemicalName = input("Choose a chemical: ")

print (chemicalName.getData())
```

but when I ran the script I got an error that said:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\test.py", line 42, in <module>
print (chemicalName.getData())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getData'
```

The idea is that when I input a chemical e.g. chemical2, I want `chemicalName` put straight into `print (chemicalName.getData())` with the value of `chemical2` which then prints the data I inputted for `chemical2 = Chemical("Data\nData\nData")`

I'm not sure what I can do at this point. To give you all an idea, I have around 150 lines of code with all the elif statements so any ideas or feedback is very welcome.

Comment: Why don't you use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Comment: `chemicalName` is a string and not an object that you are accessing a method on it. My suggestion would be that you get the basics clear. Knowing `string, tuple, dictionary, class, objects etc.` will help you use the correct data structure. Also this error is self-explanatory, knowing the basics would be an instantaneous help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary and work like this

```
class Chemical():
    def __init__(self, name, blah1, blah2):
        self.blah1 = blah1
        self.blah2 = blah2

chemicals = {}
chemical1 = Chemical("chemical1", "Data", "Data")
chemicals[chemical1.name] = chemical1
chemicalName = input("Choose a chemical: ")
if chemicalName in chemicals:
    print (chemical1.name + chemical1 + blah1 + chemical1.blah2)
else:
    print ("\nThe chemical you chose hasn't been added yet\n")
```